# Proof for, that the given series converges if $\alpha \gt 1$ & diverges Otherwise.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

So the series we are interested in is,$$\sum _2^\infty \frac{1}{n(\log n)^\alpha}$$ this one. It is said that it converges if $\alpha \gt1$ & diverges if $\alpha \le 1.$

My attempt to Proof:
For the sake of brevity, It is assumed that this inequality $2\le n\le\infty$ holds true streching upto the end of the proof.


Now, For $\alpha\le1$, 
 the inequality     $$n^\alpha\lt n(\log n)^\alpha$$ holds true which means $$\frac{1}{n(\log n)^\alpha}\lt \frac{1}{n^\alpha}$$ but the series $\sum_2^\infty\frac{1}{n^\alpha}$ is a divergent series for $\alpha\le1$, therefore $\sum_2^\infty\frac{1} {n(\log n)^\alpha}$ is divergent for $\alpha\le1.$
 For $\alpha\gt1$, function $\frac{1} {n(\log n)^\alpha}$ is positive, continuous & non increasing as $n$ increases. Therefore our required series converges if the integral $\int_2^\infty\frac{dn} {n(\log n)^\alpha}$ converges. After simplifying the improper integral, we bound to get $\frac{(\log2)^{1-\alpha}}{\alpha-1}$. For $\alpha\gt1$ the sequence will look like this, $\frac{1}{\log 2},\frac{1}{2(\log 2)^2},\frac{1}{3(\log 2)^3},\frac{1}{4(\log 2)^4},\frac{1}{5(\log 2)^5},$ & so on. And it is a converging sequence (I guess it is approaching to 0). Which means $\sum_2^\infty\frac{1}{n(\log n)^\alpha}$ for $\alpha\gt1$ is convergent.
 
** Is my approach correct?** *For proving 2nd part(i.e. for $\alpha\gt1$) I used $Theorem$ $IV$ results from Taylor & Mann's Advanced Calculus 3rd edition, 578 pages.*

Comment: You're using the comparison test wrong in the $\alpha \leq 1$ case.  That the series with the larger terms diverges is not sufficient to conclude that the series with the smaller terms diverges.  But the integral test can work on this case too.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. Give me some time to edit, i got another way to prove, by ratio test, both will diverge. Till then it's my request dont write an answer!

Comment: And for the $\alpha > 1$ case, it's not necessary to look at the sequence of improper integrals and decide if that converges.  For every $\alpha > 1$, the integral converges, so the series converges.

Comment: I will keep that in mind next time. Btw, can you formulate an answer for $\alpha\le1$ as the ratio test seems to fail at $\alpha=1$, where it diverges.

Comment: Hint for $\alpha =1$, $$ \frac{1}{n\log n}\geqslant\int_n^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x\log x} $$ because $x\mapsto\frac{1}{x\log x}$ is decreasing

Comment: I understood it as $f(x)$ becomes divergent for $\alpha=1$, because integral is divergent.